# When sharing text and image errors occur in the various versions of Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

Code is written as follows:

```
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.toString());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text.toString());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "file://" + path);

         startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, title.toString()), REQUEST_CODE);
```

The results are as follows

1. API 10 : work
2. API 14 : error

Comment: i guess you dont have the app to open such file in galaxy tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method to share photo with text. Call this method and pass argument nameofapp and imagepath. Name of app means like on which you want to share like gmail , facebook , twitter.

```
private void share(String nameApp, String imagePath) {
    try
    {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                    Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime type
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp) || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)) {
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Text");
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This photo is created by APP");
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)) );
                        targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                    }
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
                startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
 }
```

Use this like :-

```
try {
    File filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/vmphoto.jpg"; //This is imagefile path in your change it acc. to your requirement.
    share("facebook",filePath.toString());

}
catch(Exception e) {
           //exception occur might your app like gmail , facebook etc not installed or not working correctly.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.toString());
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text.toString());
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.fromFile(new File("/" + path)));
```

Comment: that thing you saw from above post first you accepted this answert few days back now wrote as same code as above and accepting this answer...

Comment: last line is changed . in android 4.0.3 dont work
`intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "file://" + path);`